# ADFS fails to send SAMLResponse to Assertion Consumer Endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, saml, adfs

I am trying to authenticate a node.js (express) web app with ADFS. I have:

- Express middleware that is redirecting to `https://adfs_host/adfs/ls` with a SAMLRequest in the url query.
- A SAML Assertion Consumer Endpoint set up as `https://my_express_app/adfs/postResponse` with binding `POST`.
- A `POST` request arriving at my `adfs/postResponse` endpoint devoid of any SAMLResponse that I understand is supposed to be present.
- Claim rules set up that should be supplying email, name, upn etc.

I don't get any error in the event viewer, just a post request with nothing in it.

Happy to supply more info but I'm not sure what info to give.

EDIT: I have found the problem, it was on the express side, not ADFS. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: you should ask the people managing adfs why they sent a post with nothing in it?

Comment: The ADFS instance is one we set up ourselves on Azure as a lab environment. Therefore I don't have an admin person to go to. The Azure environment was set up using this: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-lab-hybrid-adfs

Answer (score 1):

One possible scenario is that a SAML response is being received but the SAML response contains a "responder" error status. This means that ADFS could not process your SAML authn request for some reason. If you can confirm this is the case, you need the ADFS admin to look in the Windows event log for the specific reason. There should be one or more related error entries.

Comment: I'll have another look but as far as I can see, the request doesn't contain anything interesting. It has what looks like a tracking cookie but thats about it. There is no admin person, just me, and I can see the logs but there is no error in there (I'm pretty sure I am looking in the right place because I can change things on the SAMLRequest that cause errors and see them).

Comment: Just to be sure you're looking in the right place, the ADFS event log is under Custom Views > Server Roles > Active Directory Federation Services. ADFS will log one or more errors if it either displays an error in the browser or it returns a SAML response error status to the service provider.